# Entity Designer missing

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, designer, edmx

As the title says, somehow the entity designer disappeared from my installation of Visual Studio 2010.
When trying to open an .edmx file, it only opens it in the XML editor. When i choose "Open With...", the Entity designer doesn't show up in the list.
It has worked before, and i don't know of anything i could have done to remove it from the list. Does anyone know how i can re-add it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is, is this a problem with your project or with your VS installation.

- Try creating a new project and see if the entity designer is in the list

If it is you have two options

- Move your files to the new project
- Try to repair your project file

The way it works is that there are a set og Guids in the project file that control what is available in that project. So you can open the project files in notepad, find out which is missing and then move them over.

Comment: Thanks. in the end, completely removing VS2010 and .NET 4 and reinstalling fixed it.