# Cannot open edmx file - ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer missing "Open With"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I'm using VS 2008, Service Pack 1. Cannot open edmx file in ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer. When click open with I don't have even options to open with it.

The interesting thing it was working fine before.

I reinstalled service pack, reset settings - didn't help.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is also covered here: [Entity Designer missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724766/entity-designer-missing)

It may be faster for you to uninstall and reinstall VS, than trying to find out what the problem is.

Comment: So when I tried to create a new project and EntityDataModedel I got this error = 'Failed to load entity data model tools package. The result is -2147467259.'

Comment: Have you run ms update, do you have SP1? Also has your project set that it will only use the client side of the framework?